# Element locator did not match any elements when using SAFARI Browser in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Did anyone encounter this error?

> 15:18:40.983 INFO - Executing: [switch to frame: null])
>   15:18:40.987 INFO - Done: [switch to frame: null]
>   15:18:41.092 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.xpath: //*[(@id='header' or @name='header')]])

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide more information please?  You're getting an xpath location issue in Safari only, and not in chrome/IE?